# How to detect that Google Instant page has loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-extension, google-instant

I'm working on a browser extension (think [SEOQuake](http://www.seoquake.com/)) - I need to display some data about the search results that are shown.

Issue: If anything is added to the Google Instant results page while it's still in the process of being loaded, it'll overwrite any additions. I caught myself writing some really wonky setInterval business (waiting until the contents of `ol#rso` stop changing in size, stuff like that) so I suppose that means I'm not sure how to reliably determine if the page is done loading.

I *could* just have it wait 1-2 seconds but I really want to start fetching the data as soon as the results are loaded to save maximum amount of time.

Edit: Keep in mind, I can't use DOMElementWhatever because IE8 doesn't support it.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a good cross-browser solution yet. There are the new [Mutation Observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) and even the [Mutation Summary](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/) library to help, but no IE love. Another interesting approach using [CSS3 animation events](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/08/06/css-selector-listeners/), but no IE love :-p How about a `setInterval` hack for IE and Mutation Summary for everything else?

Comment: You might be able to use the [onpropertychange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx) event for IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {if(e.data == 'jrc') console.log('loaded')}, false);
```

That should work in IE 8+ and all other browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging

If that doesn't work in IE 8 (can't test in on my Mac right now), let me know. I believe I got some reasonably good understanding of the rs.js in the last hour. ;)

Comment: An edit that was rejected by reviewers because it should have been an answer suggested that, by now, it should say `e.data.type == 'sr'`