# How to detect when the google search page completed loaded to avoid the side-effect from instant-search

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-instant

I am currently working on a Chrome Extension that needs to read the page content from a Google search after the query has been fully input and the search page completed loaded. However, the Google instant-search brought major changes to the extension behavior.

Can I ask anyone has an idea about how to work it out (As I cannot really require the user to turn off the instant search on their computers)? By the way, the answered question: [How to detect that Google Instant page has loaded completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542052/how-to-detect-that-google-instant-page-has-loaded-completely)  does not appear to work for my extension.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII, Thank you very much for fixing these grammar errors

Comment: Your question is unclear. "Does not appear to work" how? Show us your attempt and tell us how it fails.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'll try to dig in and see if I can find an answer.