# Detecting Google Instant's SERP load completion

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-instant

I asked the [same question years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542052/how-to-detect-that-google-instant-page-has-loaded-completely), but unfortunately the answer no longer seems to work.

I've built an extension that modifies the SERPs, but the code no longer seems to work.

How can an extension detect that Google Instant search has been performed and results displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would still be the same as the (deleted) answer on your previous one - DOM Mutation listeners. You define what kind of node you're looking for, and react to it being inserted.

Since then, event-based approach became deprecated, and the new way to do it is [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

You may also want to look at the [`mutation-summary` library](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/).

Comment: You're asking about a _Chrome extension_, for [Jon's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) sake.